# Django display properties in the order as passed to values

Tags: django, django-queryset

I use Django framework and I try to run a query as below;

```
ComDiseases.objects.filter(bs_date='12/2016', district=2).values('com_disease', 'male', 'female', 'children', 'elderly')
```

The result I got is:

```
[{'elderly': 8, 'com_disease': u'Dengue', 'male': 5, 'children': 7, 'female': 6}, {'elderly': 8, 'com_disease': u'Diarrhea', 'male': 5, 'children': 7, 'female': 6}]
```

But I want my result to display properties in the same order as passed to the values, that means;

```
[{'com_disease': u'Dengue', 'male': 5, 'female': 6, 'children': 7, 'elderly': 8}, {'com_disease': u'Diarrhea', 'male': 5, 'female': 6, 'children': 7, 'elderly': 8}]
```

Is there a way I can achieve this, I read the documentation and other posts but I couldn't find any successful answer for this.

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered.

You can use `values_list`, which returns the data as lists rather than dicts; you won't get the column names though.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. That's what I wanted